# Create json sub objects using python collections module

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am attempting to build a json document to be passed to an api as a post body request.

I am pulling data from a mssql as an arrray list, then creating an ordered dictionary using collections model. Need help on how to create sub object

```
import json, collections

rowarray_list = []

for row in rows:
    t = (row.NameLine1, row.NameLine2, row.Phone, row.Mobile, 
        row.Fax, row.Slogan, row.Address, row.City, row.State, row.Zip, 
        row.Email, row.WebSite, row.ApplyOnline,
        row.Preflight, row.Facebook, row.LinkedIn, row.Username)
    rowarray_list.append(t)

objects_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['Name'] = row.NameLine1
    d['Phone'] = row.Phone
    d['Mobile'] = row.Mobile
    d['Fax'] = row.Fax
    d['Slogan']=row.Slogan
    d['Address']=row.Address
    d['City'] = row.City
    d['State'] = row.State
    d['Zip'] = row.Zip
    d['Email']=row.Email
    d['Website']=row.WebSite
    d['ApplyOnline']=row.ApplyOnline
    d['Preflight']=row.Preflight
    d['Facebook']=row.Facebook
    d['LinkedIn']=row.LinkedIn
    d['Username']=row.Username
    objects_list.append(d)

json.dumps(objects_list)
```

I want to have the json objects to be built like this:

```
{"type": "task1",
 "body": {"Name": row.NameLine
          "Phone": row.Phone
          ... }}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to do this

Comment: Your `json` format only allows for a single `body` `dict`, with no list you can't send multiple `row`s. Can you please fix your indentation. What is `rowarray_list` for?

Comment: Still little new to python and programming in general, so excuse my ignorance. I am following some of the logic used here http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2012/03/11/generate-json-from-sql-using-python/. "rowarray_list builds a list of tuples, with each row in the database becoming one tuple"

Comment: I used marshmallow library and created classes to build the dictionary and nested dictionary object for each record. I added the results to a list and then used json.dumps to build out the json based off the dictionary list I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved by using a different approach. Creating a dictionary object per each row and appending it to dictionary list. Then used json library to create the full json object

```
rowarray_list=[]    
for row in rows:
        subdt = dict(Name=row.NameLine1, Title=row.NameLine2, Phone=row.Phone, Mobile=row.Mobile, 
             Fax=row.Fax, Slogan=row.Slogan, Address=row.Address, City=row.City, State=row.State, Zip=row.Zip, Email=row.Email, WebSite=row.WebSite, ApplyOnline=row.ApplyOnline,
             Preflight=row.Preflight, Facebook=row.Facebook, LinkedIn=row.LinkedIn, Username=row.Username)
        dt=dict(action='fetchView', body=subdt)
        rowarray_list.append(dt)

print(json.dumps(rowarray_list))
cursor.close()
```